# How do I get my program to read my txt file in Java?

Tags: java

The general function of this program is to extract all the information from the txt file, input it into an array, and then compare a user inputted ID to the ones inputted into the array and return either true or false. I wrote the program, but I got an InputMismatchException. When I put the function in a try/catch statement, it returns null when I run it.

This is my Validator class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Validator
{
    private int[] valid = new int[18];

    public Validator(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int index = 0;

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                valid[index] = inputFile.nextInt();

                index++;
            }

            inputFile.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public boolean isValid(int number)
    {
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (!found && index < valid.length)
        {
          if (valid[index] == number)
          {
              found = true;
          }

          index++;
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

As for the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ChargeAccountModification
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int number;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Brandon Woodruff    12/3/16");

        System.out.print("Enter your charge account number: ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        Validator validator = new Validator("AccountNumbers.txt");

        if (validator.isValid(number) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("That's a valid account number.");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("That's an INVALID account number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is the txt information. The txt file is called AccountNumbers.txt by the way.

5658845
4520125
7895122
8777541
8451277
1302850
8080152
4562555
5552012
5050552
7825877
1250255
1005231
6545231
3852085
7576651
7881200
4581002

They actually each appear on their own line in a list, but I can't seem to get it to display like that.

Answer (score 1):

In this code :

```
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        valid[index] = inputFile.nextInt();

        index++;
    }
```

Try to replace `hasNext()` by `hasNextInt()` :

```
    while (inputFile.hasNextInt()){
        valid[index] = inputFile.nextInt();

        index++;
    }
```

Otherwise it reads a whitespace and  a whitespace is not a number.

If it doesn't work, you could also use a delimiter with a whitespace :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide stack trace with you input. I tried the same exact program with 5658845 . I got the below response

Brandon Woodruff    12/3/16
Enter your charge account number: 5658845
That's a valid account number.

But If I am entering "CDCD". I am getting your exception. So please check you input. It is the Scanner that is throwing this exception

```
Brandon Woodruff    12/3/16
Enter your charge account number: CDCD
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at ChargeAccountModification.main(ChargeAccountModification.java:15)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, because it's not printing any stack trace now for some reason. I haven't modified the program at all. This is what it was giving me:

java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at Validator.<init>(Validator.java:16)
 at ChargeAccountModification.main(ChargeAccountModification.java:17)

Comment: The inputs I was using to test the program was a copy and paste from the text file, which gave me the Exception and returned false, and 222222 which also returned false.

Comment: I ran the same exact program you gave me on eclipse and send an input 5658845 and it says a valid account number.

Comment: I ended up having my scanner use whitespace as the delimiter and apparently that made it work. I didn't think I needed to specify that, but I guess that's what I had to do.